# jqGrid plugin (Tony Tomov, Oleg Kiriljuk) - compatibility with jQuery, jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

We have an application using the jqGrid v4.5.4.
The app uses an outdated versions of jQuery (1.9.0 - packaged with jqGrid 4.5.4) and jQuery UI.
When we tried to do jQuery upgrade to v1.12. or v.2.24 and finally to v.3, we bumped into multiple issues where the upgrade process could not accept various functions in jQueryUI.
In the process, we upgraded jQueryUI from V. 1.9.0 to 1.12.1  However,  we could not find any updates of jQueryUI after September 2016 (v.1.12.1).

As jqGrid heavily relies on jQueryUI, this prevents us from using the latest jQuery versions.
Additionally, there does not seem to exist a version of jQuery UI that is compatible with jQuery 3.6.
This is rather critical as the older versions of jQuery have known security vulnerabilities.

We would really appreciate any help on the following:

- Is there a version of jqGrid that is compatible with a later (or the  latest) versions of jQuery/jQueryUI?
- If so, how should we proceed with the upgrade process?

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid 4.5.4 is 8 year old version. It is too old.

To the question:

1. The last version of  Guriddo jqGrid 5.5.5 is compatible with the
   last version of jQuery and it works with last version jQuery UI.
   Note that if you want to synchronize jqGrid with these you will need
   to select a version of jQuery which  work with jQuery UI.
2. First of all you will need to know that Guriddo jqGrid is a commertial product. In order to continue with the upgrade process, please contact our [support team](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=912)